# How long does it take to re-publish a Google Play app?

Tags: java, playback

Recently we created an Android app and submitted it to the Google Play app store. It took a week for them to review it, publish it and it went live. Recently we wanted to remove it temporarily from the Google Play app store, so we thought about un-publishing it to remove it. If we un-publish it, then try to re-publish it, does Google have to re-review the app? It took a week last time and we only want to temporarily remove it (say for like 12-24 hours) from the Google Play app store. If Google does not need to re-review it, typically how long does it take once we re-publish it does it take to appear in the Google Play store? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Stack Overflow is not Google Play Store support.

Comment: You would do well to read the Stack Overflow [help file](https://stackoverflow.com/help) at this time, paying special attention to the section describing what is and is not considered [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: @MarsAtomic thanks for being completely useless. Looking for that answer also.

Comment: OP - did you figure it out?

Comment: @ArturMalendowicz And it seems you have mistaken Stack Overflow for Google Support as well. You've been a member here for longer than I have and still haven't figured out that SO is for specific technical issues, not product support for a commercial concern. In seven years, have you read the help file? Even once? How do you suppose people would know anything about Play Store's internal review policy -- unless they were at Google? Consider meditating on the definition of "useless" while gazing deeply into a mirror.